# Autolayout constrain apply programmatically in xcode 8 print warning

Tags: ios, constraints, swift3, xcode8

I have recently convert my application in swift 3.0 for support in ios 10 after converting it , I make some cell programmatically in xcode 8.0 but when i run in ios 9 or 8 device it print warning of the constraint but if i run in ios 10 it run with out any warning. I tested same cell in ios 9.3 and 8.4 version. Any reason for this thing.

```
func createView()
    {
        setupdata()
        let objView = UIView()
        objView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.contentView.addSubview(objView)


        objView.addSubview(lblTitle)
        objView.addSubview(textField)

        let views = ["lblTitle":lblTitle,"textFeild":textField,"objView":objView] as [String : Any]

        let metrics = ["lblHeight":isIPad ? 60 : 40,"size":isIPad ? 20 : 10]

        objView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[lblTitle(gap)]-[textFeild]|", options: [], metrics: ["gap" : (isIPad ? 150.0 : 100.0)], views: views))

        objView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[lblTitle(lblHeight)]|", options: [], metrics: metrics , views: views))
        objView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[textFeild(lblHeight)]|", options: [], metrics: metrics , views: views))

        self.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-size-[objView]-size-|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
        self.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[objView]|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))

    }

    func setupdata()
    {

        lblTitle = UILabel()
        lblTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lblTitle.textColor = .gray
        lblTitle.font = getFontGotham_Medium(getSizeForDeviceType(14.0, ipadFSize: 18.0, iphoneFSize: 11.0,iphone4SFSize: 10.0))

        textField = UITextField()
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.font = getFontGotham_Medium(getSizeForDeviceType(14.0, ipadFSize: 18.0, iphoneFSize: 11.0,iphone4SFSize: 10.0))

        textField.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: textField, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 40))

          lblTitle.text = "Email Address"
          textField.text = ""
    }
```

**Error**

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15dcaf40 H:[UITextField:0x15ececc0(40)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1712b090 H:|-(0)-[UILabel:0x15e831c0'Email Address']   (Names: '|':UIView:0x15d4cd00 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1714b200 H:[UILabel:0x15e831c0'Email Address'(100)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1714f940 H:[UILabel:0x15e831c0'Email Address']-(NSSpace(8))-[UITextField:0x15ececc0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1714f970 H:[UITextField:0x15ececc0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x15d4cd00 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15ee0880 H:|-(10)-[UIView:0x15d4cd00]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x15daf590 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17120c80 H:[UIView:0x15d4cd00]-(10)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x15daf590 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15ec2300 'fittingSizeHTarget' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x15daf590(320)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15dcaf40 H:[UITextField:0x15ececc0(40)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```